# How to show this Non-Exact Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

Solve the following differential equation :

$$x \sin(y)dx+(x+1)\cos(y) dy$$

Here's where i'm stuck.
I've let *M=x siny* and *N=(x+1)cosy*

Differentiating partially for both $M_y$=*x cosy* and $N_x$=*cosy*

$\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}$=$\frac{x-1}{x+1}$

I used a trick such that instead of *x-1* I used *x+1-2* and integrated to get my integrating factor as $e^x - \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

Now what do I do? I've tried multiplying my original equation by my integrating factor but it's long and disgusting and seems wrong. I have no idea how to proceed from here can anyone advise me

Comment: do you meant $$x\sin(y)dx+(x+1)\cos(y)dy=0$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if so then write your equation in the form
$$\frac{x}{x+1}dx=-\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)}dy$$